# Does mastodon has advance search

Tags: search, mastodon

I'd like to search all post from a particular account by specific word.
Similar to twitter advanced search =

`(key) (from:joinmastodon)`

I haven't found the way how to do it.

Any advice would be appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible (intentionally / by design).

Mastodon supports search on hashtags and user names on a local instance, or (*if ElasticSearch is available and the instance administrator has enabled it*) for a user's own content in full text, but *not* across the whole database. See the [documentation](https://docs.joinmastodon.org/admin/optional/elasticsearch/):

> Mastodon supports full-text search when ElasticSearch is available.
> Mastodon’s full-text search allows logged in users to find results
> from their own statuses, their mentions, their favourites, and their
> bookmarks. It deliberately does not allow searching for arbitrary
> strings in the entire database.

Answer (score 2):

While search results in Mastodon are limited to posts that you have (a) posted, (b) favorited, (c) bookmarked, or that (d) mention you, I have found through experimentation that you *can* use `from:` to limit results to a specific user (confirmed on Mastodon 4.1.4).

So a search term like:

`stackoverflow from:@user@example.com`

Will show you posts from @user@example.com that contain "stackoverflow" *as long as* those posts meet any of the four above criteria.

As far as I know, this is not documented anywhere, and there may be other search parameters that I haven't discovered yet. (Sort would be nice.)